# Flutter demo app doesn't work, detects problems

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a problem with demo app in flutter. I don't know why but Visual Studio Code keeps detecting problems right after I create the project. I can't start the app.

I tried reinstalling VSC, Android Studio and all the extensions. Nothing works. Everything worked fine before I upgraded my RAM. Could that be the issue somehow?
problems that it detects

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and run `flutter pub get`.

Also you can open `pubspec.yaml` and click

[image]

Comment: This made the problems disappear for like a second but they showed again. :(

Comment: Is it happening for counter app?

Comment: exactly, i didn't have a problem with that last week

Comment: can you run `flutter doctor -v` and check if there any other issue

Comment: It's all green in flutter doctor :(

Comment: try to create another project

Comment: I tried creating so many projects, it still wont work...

Comment: ok, try to reset the flutter.  try `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.3.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 52b3dc25f6 (11 days ago) • 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: Can you share your main.dart

Comment: am i supposed to just copy paste it here?

Comment: try to use pastebin if you failed to include on question

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1QEFtczT

Comment: regular snippet, try to restart the ide/pc

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: restart your computer and check

Comment: oh you meant that haha 
i restarted it for a couple of times, it doesnt change anything

Comment: Sorry dont know. How about reinstalling the flutter from scratch

Comment: ive been thinking about that and i guess thats what im gonna do

Comment: reinstalling flutter worked :)